# how to fetch word from url in php?

Tags: php

url string

```
http://localhost/magento_prac/index.php/electronics/computers.html
http://localhost/magento_prac/index.php/electronics/cell-phones.html
```

I want to fetch 'computers' from url. ex 'computers', 'cell-phones'

Comment: can you use any framework?

Comment: yes magento.but i want to fetch last word from url string

Comment: Are you trying to extract the words from the URL or download the page at the URL and then extract something from that page?

Comment: No.I want to fetch last word from url because its category url key. i am use category url key pass to onther opration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
$category = preg_replace('/^.*\/(.*)\.html$/', '$1', $url);
```

The regular expression matches everything (`.*`) from the start (`^`) of the string up until the last / (`\/`). Then, it matches everything (`.*`) again except for the `.html` at the end and expects the string to end after that (`$`).

The brackets around the second `.*` allow you to reference that part of the match in the substitution as `$1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert URL into attay and fetch last element with array_pop():

```
$urlArray = explode('/', $url);
$word = substr(array_pop($urlArray),0,-5);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
//get the url
$url = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);

//seperate the segments using explode()
$segments = explode('/', $url);

//and get the last segment
$last = explode('.', end($segments));

//use the last segment
echo $last[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

For convenience, here's another option:

```
$url = 'http://localhost/magento_prac/index.php/electronics/computers.html';
$category = pathinfo($url)['filename']; // "computers"
```

---

Above example assumes the application is running at least on PHP 5.4 to use array de-referencing.

> [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) - Returns information about a file path.

```
'dirname' => string 'http://localhost/magento_prac/index.php/electronics'
'basename' => string 'computers.html'
'extension' => string 'html'
'filename' => string 'computers'
```